# I can not run the microsoft python extension code from github

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

1. I download code from https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python.
2. enter "npm i". showing lots of red.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0jAj.jpg
3. enter "vsce package". showing lots of error.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtYfT.jpg
4. I want to change some code and generate a vsix file for visual-studio-code. How can I run the code?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, npm is a package manager for JavaScript.

1. First download pip and Anaconda to install and manage your Python related packages. If you are working from a macOS machine you can use Homebrew as well. [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/getting-started/) [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
2. Create your virtual enviornment that contains all of the dependencies you need to run your python program. [How to create virtual enviornments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)
3. Activate your virtual enviornment. For example, on a Windows machine do:

   ```
   source activate your_enviornment_name
   ```
4. Your Python file should be named file_name.py not .vsix .
5. If you need additional extensions within VS Code you can install those directly in the IDE by accessing the Extensions Marketplace (App Store inside Visual Studio Code)
6. You can edit and debug in VS Code.

Comment: I do not mean to run python code. I want to run the vscode extension code.